# Open Window in new tab using an ASP.NET Button, C#, and the code behind the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am working on a website that produces internal reports and I have been tasked with opening those reports in a new tab/window with the restriction that any scripts must be run from the code behind and not written in the html/aspx portion of the website.

my current attempt at testing the code is this:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('http://www.google.com','_newtab');", true);
    }
```

The Button code is:

```
     <td>
          <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="83px" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
     </td>
```

This is a direct grab from the example project that shows how to do this. the problem is that nothing happens. it's as if the code is getting skipped over by Visual Studio. I have also checked that all of the same items are in the "Using" section at the top of the code. do i need to have a script manager or something? does anyone have suggestions on what i may be overlooking?

Comment: marked answer ?

Answer (score 1):

> Seems you are trying to open `new window` on `button click` but `_newtab` which is not valid.

You should try this way:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('http://www.microsoft.com', '_blank');", true);
```

***`Update:`***

**`Your .CS File`**

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('http://www.microsoft.com', '_blank');", true);

    }
```

**`Your Aspx File`**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

         <asp:Button Text="Open New Window" OnClick="ButtonClick"  type="button" runat="server" />

        </div>


    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it would help what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Before anything, you should copy and paste the answer and test it, once its solved, then should find the difference soon you got it then update mistaken part. This is how should you proceed.

Comment: `string script = String.Format("window.open('{0}','YourWindowName','fullscreen=yes,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,status=yes');", url);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OPEN_WINDOW", script, true);`

Comment: another suggestion about it

Comment: Thanks for your comment you can also post as an answer if you wish.